Polars - issues with performance - attempting to create a new dataframe per row
I need to run another library's algo on each row of a large df but am having trouble converting my code to polars expressions for better performance. Here are a couple sample DFs:
df_products = pl.DataFrame({
    'SKU':['apple','banana','carrot','date'],
    'DESCRIPTION': [
        "Wire Rope",
        "Connector",
        "Tap",
        "Zebra"
    ],
    'CATL3': [
        "Fittings",
        "Tube",
        "Tools",
        "Animal"
    ],
    'YELLOW_CAT': [
        "Rope Accessories",
        "Tube Fittings",
        "Forming Taps",
        "Striped"
    ],
    'INDEX': [0, 5, 25, 90],
    'EMBEDDINGS': [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9],
        [10,11,12]
    ],
})


df_items_sm_ex = pl.DataFrame({
    'PRODUCT_INFO':['apple','banana','carrot'],
    'SEARCH_SIMILARITY_SCORE': [
        [1., 0.87, 0.54, 0.33],
        [1., 0.83, 0.77, 0.55],
        [1., 0.92, 0.84, 0.65]
    ],
    'SEARCH_POSITION': [
        [0, 5, 25, 90],
        [1, 2, 151, 373],
        [3, 5, 95, 1500]
    ],
    'SKU':['apple','banana','carrot'],
    'YELLOW_CAT': [
        "Rope Accessories",
        "Tube Fittings",
        "Forming Taps"
    ],
    'CATL3': [
        "Fittings",
        "Tube",
        "Tools"
    ],
    'EMBEDDINGS': [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]
    ],
})

and now the code
Per each row I have 3 main operations: Generate the base new dataframe, preprocess / clean / run predictions on the dataframe, write the dataframe to a few SQL tables. I have noticed step 1 and 2 easily take the longest time to execute:
df_items_sm_ex.select(
        pl.struct(df_items_sm_ex.columns)
        .map_elements(lambda row: build_complements(
            row, df_items, rfc, rfc_comp, engine, current_datetime
            )))


def build_complements(row, df_products, ml, ml_comp, engine, current_datetime):
    try:
        #step 1 - generate the base new dataframe
        output_df = build_candidate_dataframe(row, df_products)
        #step 2 - preprocess / clean / run predictions on the dataframe
        output_df = process_candidate_output(df_products, output_df, ml, ml_comp)
        #step 3 write dataframes to SQL
        write_validate_complements(output_df, row, current_datetime, engine)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'exception: {repr(e)}')

def build_candidate_dataframe(row, df_products):
    df_len = len(row['SEARCH_SIMILARITY_SCORE'])
    schema = {'QUERY': str,
              'SIMILARITY_SCORE': pl.Float32, 
              'POSITION': pl.Int64,
              'QUERY_SKU': str, 
              'QUERY_LEAF': str,
              'QUERY_CAT': str,
              'QUERY_EMBEDDINGS': pl.List(pl.Float32)
            }
    output_df = pl.DataFrame({'QUERY': [row['PRODUCT_INFO']] * df_len,
                    'SIMILARITY_SCORE': row['SEARCH_SIMILARITY_SCORE'], 
                    'POSITION': row['SEARCH_POSITION'],
                    'QUERY_SKU': [row['SKU']] * df_len, 
                    'QUERY_LEAF': [row['YELLOW_CAT']] * df_len,
                    'QUERY_CAT': [row['CATL3']] * df_len,
                    'QUERY_EMBEDDINGS': [row['EMBEDDINGS']] * df_len
                    }, schema=schema).sort("SIMILARITY_SCORE", descending=True)
                
    output_df = output_df.join(df_products[['SKU', 'EMBEDDINGS', 'INDEX', 'DESCRIPTION', 'CATL3', 'YELLOW_CAT']], left_on=['POSITION'], right_on=['INDEX'], how='left')
    output_df = output_df.rename({"DESCRIPTION": "SIMILAR_PRODUCT_INFO", "CATL3": "SIMILAR_PRODUCT_CAT", "YELLOW_CAT": "SIMILAR_PRODUCT_LEAF"})
    return output_df

def process_candidate_output(df_products, output_df, ml, ml_comp):
    combined_embeddings = (output_df.to_pandas()['QUERY_EMBEDDINGS'] + output_df.to_pandas()['EMBEDDINGS']) / 2
    output_df = output_df.with_columns(pl.Series(name='COMBINED_EMBEDDINGS', values=combined_embeddings))
    output_df = output_df[['QUERY', 'QUERY_SKU', 'QUERY_CAT', 'QUERY_LEAF', 'SIMILAR_PRODUCT_INFO', 'SIMILAR_PRODUCT_CAT', 'SIMILAR_PRODUCT_LEAF', 'SIMILARITY_SCORE', 'COMBINED_EMBEDDINGS', 'SKU', 'POSITION']]
    output_df = output_df.filter(
        pl.col('SKU') != output_df['QUERY_SKU'][0]
    )
    #ML predictions
    output_df = predict_complements(output_df, ml)
    output_df = output_df.filter(
        pl.col('COMPLEMENTARY_PREDICTIONS') == 1
    )
    #Other ML predictions
    output_df = predict_required_accessories(output_df, ml_comp)
    output_df = output_df.sort(by='LABEL_PROBABILITY', descending=True)
    return output_df


Can you provide a minimal runnable example with an input dataframe along with the expected output? What are predict_complements and predict_required_accessories doing? It sounds like these steps might be heavy on compute.

You should strive to not create python objects that you then use to create a new df. Perhaps you should pare this question down to refactoring build_candidate_dataframe so that you aren't doing that. In its current form, I'd not try to answer this question as it requires making too many assumptions about what (as an example) row, df_products or lookup_dict look like.

@DeanMacGregor I have updated with an example of df_products. I removed lookup_dict. Can you explain your thoughts a bit further on 'You should strive to not create python objects that you then use to create a new df.'? In my particular case, the df_products dataframe represents a long list of items. I need to create recommendations for each item; therefore I generate a new df... maybe you understand my intention but I believe I am not clearly seeing your solution. Thanks

@Hericks I gave an update to the post, let me know if this is not enough. predict_complements use a random forest to label the dataframe if each item is True or False. Of the True labels, predict_required_accessories runs a separately trained random forest to break down the True labels into 3 different categories.

For each row of the df you're pulling the data out of polars and into python objects and then you're reinitiating a polars df. That is very expensive both in time and memory. Instead you should keep everything in polars memory unless for some reason you absolutely can't. You mention that most of the time is taken in steps 1 and step 2 but step 2 includes your ML stuff so that might still be the bottleneck.
Using map_elements here isn't ideal because you're not returning anything back to the df, just use a regular for loop. Also I combined your two functions into this one:
def build_and_process_candidate_output(i, df_items_sm_ex, df_products, ml, ml_comp):
    output_df = (
        df_items_sm_ex[i]
        .explode("SEARCH_SIMILARITY_SCORE", "SEARCH_POSITION")
        .rename(
            {
                "PRODUCT_INFO": "QUERY",
                "SEARCH_SIMILARITY_SCORE": "SIMILARITY_SCORE",
                "SEARCH_POSITION": "POSITION",
                "SKU": "QUERY_SKU",
                "YELLOW_CAT": "QUERY_LEAF",
                "CATL3": "QUERY_CAT",
                "EMBEDDINGS": "QUERY_EMBEDDINGS",
            }
        )
        .join(
            df_products.select(
                "SKU", "EMBEDDINGS", "INDEX", "DESCRIPTION", "CATL3", "YELLOW_CAT"
            ),
            left_on=["POSITION"],
            right_on=["INDEX"],
            how="left",
        )
        .rename(
            {
                "DESCRIPTION": "SIMILAR_PRODUCT_INFO",
                "CATL3": "SIMILAR_PRODUCT_CAT",
                "YELLOW_CAT": "SIMILAR_PRODUCT_LEAF",
            }
        )
        .select(
            "QUERY",
            "QUERY_SKU",
            "QUERY_CAT",
            "QUERY_LEAF",
            "SIMILAR_PRODUCT_INFO",
            "SIMILAR_PRODUCT_CAT",
            "SIMILAR_PRODUCT_LEAF",
            "SIMILARITY_SCORE",
            
            # This assumes these are the same length
            (pl.col("QUERY_EMBEDDINGS").explode() + pl.col("EMBEDDINGS").explode())
            .implode()
            .over("POSITION")
            .alias("COMBINED_EMBEDDINGS"),

            "SKU",
            "POSITION",
        )
         # Given the sample data, this filter makes everything go away
         # which is why supplying good sample data is important
        .filter(pl.col("SKU") != pl.col("QUERY_SKU").first())
    )

    # ML predictions
    output_df = predict_complements(output_df, ml)
    output_df = output_df.filter(pl.col("COMPLEMENTARY_PREDICTIONS") == 1)
    # Other ML predictions
    output_df = predict_required_accessories(output_df, ml_comp)
    output_df = output_df.sort(by="LABEL_PROBABILITY", descending=True)
    return output_df


Thank you very much, this sped up the execution speed by 10x. I am new to polars and the way you framed the code will help me in my future use cases with polars.
